# What is the purpose of button like blinking

Tags: identification, battery-operated

My father was an electric engineer who passed away 12 years ago. Today I found this component in our house, it works with two LR927 batteries. There is no cable (only a cotton like rope attached to the back panel) or button outside of the thing. If you close the back panel hard enough it will start blinking red and blue constantly. What is purpose of this component? There is no additional part to un-assemble. I tried Google Lens and no luck for it. Could you help me to identify it?

[image: blue light blinking]
[image: backpanel]
[image: no battery state]
[image: size]

Comment: It's a toy.....

Comment: It's a blinking LED intended for decoration. Can also help finding items in the dark.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DKNguyen but are you sure? Because it's very small to be a toy; a baby could swallow it easily. And for a kid, red and blue led lights not big/bright enough to get an attention. it looks like part of burglar alarm transmitter. But still i don't see any additional part in it.

Comment: it's probably from a larger toy, like a ball ... the cotton thread indicates that it may have been sown into something

Comment: Similar items were given away as advertisements for a product. They would be mounted behind a plastic sheet imprinted with the products logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a cheap piece of jewelry. You can buy them for about a dollar each when you buy 25 at a time.

> it looks like part of burglar alarm transmitter.

It doesn't look like any burglar alarm transmitter I've ever seen, although I haven't seen all of them. It's made like a toy.

There are likely many variants of this design made using similar tooling, with details varying across time and space, so to speak. Some of them are not earrings but pendants, for example. There are probably millions of the things made yearly.

And just googling "blinking earring" brings this picture, which is just another version of the same thing.

[image: Picture of a blinking earring]

It came from [this Amazon listing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0099TOVG2).

Comment: Another possible use is to attach to a black cat's collar to help locate it at night. Works rather well